# Solr Replication Error : SnapPull Failed

Tags: solr, lucene, replication

My slave server is replicating with master, that has very large index. however, I am seeing this error :

SnapPull failed :org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to download _avx.fdx completely. Downloaded 0!=3748828, very frequently

Unfortunately, the stacktrace is very thin and the error message is not very descriptive either, so I left to debug this issue myself, i did following :

Searched on stackoverflow to see if anybody else facing the issue and found this posts :- [solr ReplicationHandler - SnapPull failed to download files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691156/solr-replicationhandler-snappull-failed-to-download-files), wherein the user had to replace the http jars because of some garbage in the response. Though I din't see such message in the response, I went and replaced the http common jars but not much use!.

Have even tried the lucene mailinglist, but haven't got affirmative answer.

Additionally, I also see many index.timestamp directories, which I believe solr creates to download the index files during replication. Curious why aren't they getting deleted ?

If somebody has any faced this issue, please throw some light, would be very grateful.

Comment: I'm also having this problem, did you manage to fix it?

Comment: @damau, sorry little late to respond. I don't have a strong answer on the root cause, though what I learned is, if you continue to commit documents as the replication is in progress, there's possibility that you would run into this case. Though what I learned is this error is recoverable and you may not see this error on your next run.